# Swift protocol delegate returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I set a breakpoint in the didConnect function to print out the value of delegate, and it is coming back as `nil` and I have not clue why

```
@objc protocol KestrelDeviceConnectDelegate {
    func didConnect()
    func didDisconnect()
}

@objcMembers
class KestrelDeviceConnect: NSObject{


    static let singleton = KestrelDeviceConnect()
    public weak var delegate: KestrelDeviceConnectDelegate?

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.isInitialReading = false
        self.kestrelIsConnected = true
        kestrelPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        delegate?.didConnect()

    }

}
```

in `viewDidLoad` in my destination VC

```
_kestrelVC = [[KestrelDeviceConnect alloc]init];
[_kestrelVC setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to assign a value to the `delegate` property?

Comment: in a VC viewDidLoad file I call ```kestrelVC = [[KestrelDeviceConnect alloc]init];
    [_kestrelVC setDelegate:self];```

Comment: that call is in the same VC that I need to call a function in

Comment: Show that `viewDidLoad` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was initializing a new `KestrelDeviceConnect` instance, so instead of having `_kestrelVC = [[KestrelDeviceConnect alloc]init];` what worked was `_kestrelVC = [KestrelDeviceConnect singleton]`